# How to create a List when reading from a stored procedure with three select statements c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a list of the info I get from my columns in my stored procedure. I run three select statements in my stored procedure. One returns one row 6 columns. The other two return 3 columns and 8 rows.

example:

```
A B C D E F//select one
one row of results
G H I//select two
8 rows of results
G H I//select three
8 rows of results
```

The problem is I get an index is out of range exception where I assign my list its values. I am guessing it is because of the two statements that it returns, because they both say FaultStart? I thought about limiting my reader to the first 8 rows but then what about the last 8 I need. How can I get the return of both of my select statements that have the same row name?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("L_getDownTimeByLine", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker3.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Value = 1;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();

List<string> test = new List<string>();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    Line1ADT = dr["A Line Down Time"].ToString();
    Line1ADP = dr["A Line Percentage"].ToString();
    Line1BDT = dr["B Line Down Time"].ToString();
    Line1BDP = dr["B Line Percentage"].ToString();
    Line1TDT = dr["Total Down Time"].ToString();
    Line1TDP = dr["Total Percentage"].ToString();
    test.Add((dr["FaultStart"].ToString()));//here is where my problem is.

}
dr.Close();
```

I apologize for any confusion regarding this question. Not sure how to approach asking it other than stating what I am trying to accomplish.

Stack Trace

> ```
>  at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
>   at DownTimeReports_RackLine.testExcelReport() in c:\Users\ Software\WebSite1\DownTimeReports\DownTimeTotals.aspx.cs:line 193
>   at DownTimeReports_RackLine.GenerateButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\\Software\WebSite1\DownTimeReports\DownTimeTotals.aspx.cs:line 133
>   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton.OnClick(ButtonClickEventArgs e)
>   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> ```

stored procedure

```
    SET @QueryA = N'
select min(DateAndTime) as FaultStart, max(DateAndTime) as FaultEnd, cast(max(DateAndTime) - min(DateAndTime) as time) as DownTime
from (select pt.*,
             sum(case when datediff(second, prevdt, DateAndTime) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (order by DateAndTime) as grp
      from (select pt.*, lag(DateAndTime) over (order by DateAndTime) as prevdt
            from IncomingProductTracker pt
            where ' + @lineAvariable + ' = 1 and
                 DateAndTime > @startTime1 and
                  DateAndTime < @endTime1
           ) pt
     ) pt
     group by grp
having cast(max(DateAndTime) - min(DateAndTime) as time) < @breakAllowance1
order by FaultStart';

SET @ParamsA = N'@startTime1 datetime, @endTime1 datetime, @breakAllowance1 time(0)';

SET @QueryB = N'
select min(DateAndTime) as FaultStart, max(DateAndTime) as FaultEnd, cast(max(DateAndTime) - min(DateAndTime) as time) as DownTime
from (select pt.*,
             sum(case when datediff(second, prevdt, DateAndTime) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (order by DateAndTime) as grp
      from (select pt.*, lag(DateAndTime) over (order by DateAndTime) as prevdt
            from IncomingProductTracker pt
            where ' + @lineBvariable + ' = 1 and
                 DateAndTime > @startTime1 and
                  DateAndTime < @endTime1
           ) pt
     ) pt
     group by grp
having cast(max(DateAndTime) - min(DateAndTime) as time) < @breakAllowance1
order by FaultStart';

SET @ParamsB = N'@startTime1 datetime, @endTime1 datetime, @breakAllowance1 time(0)';

declare @tempA table (
    FaultStart datetime,
    FaultEnd datetime,
    DownTime time(0))

declare @tempB table (
    FaultStart datetime,
    FaultEnd datetime,
    DownTime time(0))

insert into @tempA (FaultStart, FaultEnd, DownTime)
    EXEC sp_executesql @QueryA, @ParamsA, @startTime1 = @startTime, @endTime1 = @endTime, @breakAllowance1 = @breakAllowance;
insert into @tempB (FaultStart, FaultEnd, DownTime)
    EXEC sp_executesql @QueryB, @ParamsB, @startTime1 = @startTime, @endTime1 = @endTime, @breakAllowance1 = @breakAllowance;

select @aLineDownTime as [A Line Down Time], convert(nvarchar, @aLinePercentage) + '%' as [A Line Percentage], @bLineDownTime as [B Line Down Time], convert(nvarchar, @bLinePercentage) + '%' as [B Line Percentage], @totalDownTime as [Total Down Time], convert(nvarchar, @totalPercentage) + '%' as [Total Percentage]

--Here's what we return, 3 different select statements
select *
FROM @tempA

select *
FROM @tempB
```

Comment: Can you please add either the `exception.Message` or the stack trace to your post?

Comment: I have several ideas on what is going wrong, but without seeing the sql that you're returning, it doesnt make sense to speculate.  Could you post your sproc? (or at least the relevant sql of what is being returned)

Comment: @Brandon yes hang on.

Comment: @Brandon trace it up.

Comment: @paqogomez added the stored procedure.(relevant parts)

Comment: Ya, i've never tried to do what you're doing here, so thats 1 red flag.  This might be better suited to 2 different sprocs, 1 with the temp tables and the other with the linedowntime.  At the very least, putting these into a `union all` would fix your problem because you'd be forced to make a value for all 5 columns.

Comment: Which `SELECT` are you trying to return in your `test.Add()` above?

Comment: @Brandon that is the second SELECT.

Comment: @paqogomez so why union all them and have the unnecessary space taken up?

Comment: Check out this link, it has a lot to say about what you are doing. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620635/Stored-procedures-and-multiple-result-sets-in-T-SQ

Comment: @paqogomez if I'm going to union all I should probably put the other results into a temp table also correct?